# Symfony2: if ($boolean == null) is true if boolean is false

Tags: php, symfony

I have a questionnaire with Yes/No radio buttons which I am saving into my database as booleans. For specific reason, the form does not have validation and all fields are nullable, so half the form can be filled in now and half later. At one point in my code, I have to check whether the form has been completely filled in.

My problem is that if the radio button has been set to NO (i.e: FALSE. 0 in database instead of null), then `if ($boolean == null)` still evaluates to true. `print ">>$boolean<<";` for a boolean which is false, results in `>><<` whereas `var_dump($boolean);` results in `bool(false)`. How do I determine, in Symfony2, if the boolean value has not been filled in (NULL in database) as opposed to marked as false (0 in database)?

Comment: `$boolean === null` (note the **3** equals signs) for strict comparison? value AND type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the PHP comparison table (https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), `false == NULL`. You need to use the `===` operator in order to make a strict comparison in this case, so try using `if($boolean === null)` instead.